# Подключение виртуального клиента к виртуальному роутеру vmware workstation

Tags: linux, debian, vmware

Физическая машина на Debian 9. На ней запущены два экземпляра vmware ws, назовем их virtualrouter и virtualstation, оба тоже debian. virtualrouter коннектится к интернету через vpn (в это время физическая машина пускает свой траффик напрямую через провайдера). virtualstation лишена связи с внешним интернетом, имеет только адаптер host-only. Как раздать интернет с virtualrouter на virtualstation? Чтобы у virtualstation был ip-адрес vpn, а не моего провайдера

Comment: как насчет виртуального свича? потом прокинешь впн через свич